# how to add 0's into a name with series numbers

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this. I generated the fourth column (taxa) which combine the first three columns. But I want to add one or two zeros after the letters "DC" or "PD" if the nchar(df$acno) == 5 or nchar(df$acno) == 4. So that the string in the taxa column would be two letter (DC or PD) plus 6 digits plus the character(s) from column acs if any.
I used "paste" or "substr" function to add "0" it gave me a similar waring: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. Great appreciate the helps if anyone can help me a best solution. 
The taxa column is expected as:

```
taxa
DC003654-1
DC004002B
DC004007B
DC002108
DC019976-1
DC029333
PD054606-1
PD086138R
PD019986
PD229333


df = read.table(text="acp   acno    acs bran    taxa
DC  3654    -1  3   DC3654-1
DC  4002    B   3   DC4002B
DC  4007    B   3   DC4007B
DC  2108        2.5 DC2108
DC  19976   -1  2.5 DC19976-1
DC  29333       3   DC29333
PD  54606   -1  4   PD54606-1
PD  86138   R   3   PD86138R
PD  19986       3   PD19986
PD  229333      2.5 PD229333", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with(df, paste0(acp, sprintf("%06d",acno), acs) )
# [1] "DC003654-1" "DC004002B"  "DC004007B"  "DC002108"   "DC019976-1"
# [6] "DC029333"   "PD054606-1" "PD086138R"  "PD019986"   "PD229333"
```